# Stack of strings with templates?

Tags: c++, class, stack

I'm trying to make a push function for my class Stack but I keep getting errors. This is my code: (before you ask, I know using namespace std is a bad idea; we are required to use it now...).

header:

```
#pragma once
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;
template <class T>
class Stack {
    T List[100];
    int size;
public:
    Stack() : size(0){}
    void push(const T &x)
    {
        strcpy(List[size++], x);
    }
    const T& pop() {
        if (size != 0) return List[size - 1];
    }
    T print()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            cout << List[i] << " ";
    }
    T reverse();
};
```

main

```
#include <iostream>
#include"Stack.h"
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    Stack<string> S;
    S.push("ana");
    S.push("are");
    S.push("mere");
    S.print();
}
```

my error is in strcpy: cannot convert argument 1 from T to char * .

Comment: `strcpy` was the wrong choice. Why did you choose to not use assignment?

Comment: @molbdnilo you're right, thanks. Guess I'm way to confused to make sense in my code now

Comment: I don't believe "I know using namespace std is a bad idea; we are required to use it now...". Are you sure? If so, please ask *why*.

Comment: @cigien it was a test, so no questions were asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `strcpy` here, you can just use `=` to assign the input:

```
void push(const T &x)
{
   List[size++] = x;
}
```

There are some other issues in your code. In `pop`, you are not decrementing `size`, and you are not returning if the `List` is empty. One option is just to `throw` if there is nothing to return:

```
const T& pop() 
{
    if (size != 0) 
        return List[size--];
    throw;
}
```

Also, you are not returning from `print`. However, there doesn't appear to be any meaningful value to return, so you could make it a `void` function:

```
void print()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
         cout << List[i] << " "; 
}
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/N_huS7).